Why does the callback function for the 'drawingstarted' event in Azure Map not return any parameters?
add(eventType: "drawingchanged" | "drawingchanging" | "drawingcomplete" | "drawingstarted" | "drawingerased", target: atlas.drawing.DrawingManager, callback: (e: azmaps.Shape) => void): void;
 const map = new atlas.Map(ref.current as HTMLElement, {})

 map.events.add('ready', function () {
  const drawingToolbar = new drawing.control.DrawingToolbar({
    position: 'top-right',
    style: 'light',
    buttons: [
      drawing.drawing.DrawingMode.drawLine,
      drawing.drawing.DrawingMode.eraseGeometry,
    ],
  });
  //Create an instance of the drawing manager and display the drawing toolbar.
  const drawingManager = new drawing.drawing.DrawingManager(map, {
    interactionType: 'click',
    toolbar: drawingToolbar,
  });

  mapInstance.events.add('drawingstarted', drawingManager, (e)=>{ console.log(e) // null});
});


The drawingstarted event in Azure Maps doesn’t return any parameters because it is designed to signal the start of a drawing action rather than provide specific details about the drawing itself. This event is primarily used to trigger actions or changes in the UI when a drawing begins, rather than to convey information about the drawing.Here is the eample of drawingchanged, drawingchanging, or drawingcomplete in the ui

Should the drawingStarted event consider including a parameter e: azmaps.Shape? Omitting it might result in an inaccurate TypeScript type annotation. My goal is to access getProperties().parent_id and the initial click coordinates when line drawing commences.

The drawingstarted event in Azure Maps does not return any parameters because it is designed to signal the beginning of a drawing action rather than provide specific details about the drawing itself.
This event is primarily used to trigger actions or changes in the UI when a drawing begins, rather than to convey information about the drawing.
Here is an example of drawingchanged, drawingchanging, or drawingcomplete in the UI.
The code below demonstrates how to set up and manage events with the Azure Maps Drawing Tools.
Thanks  @cschotte for the sample  Azure Maps Drawing .
  var map, drawingManager, drawingEvents = ['drawingchanged', 'drawingchanging', 'drawingcomplete', 'drawingmodechanged', 'drawingstarted', 'drawingerased'];

        function getMap() {
            map = new atlas.Map('myMap', {
                center: [-122.33, 47.6],
                zoom: 12,
                view: 'Auto',
                authOptions: {
                    authType: 'anonymous',
                    clientId: 'e6b6ab59', 
                    getToken: function (resolve, reject, map) {
                        var tokenServiceUrl = 'https://samples.azuremaps.com/api/GetAzureMapsToken';

                        fetch(tokenServiceUrl).then(r => r.text()).then(token => resolve(token));
                    }
            map.events.add('ready', function () {
                drawingManager = new atlas.drawing.DrawingManager(map, {
                    toolbar: new atlas.control.DrawingToolbar({ position: 'top-right', style: 'light' })
                });



For your goal of accessing getProperties().parent_id and the initial click coordinates, you might consider using the drawingchanging or drawingchanged events.
with parent_id:
  function createHighlightEvent(eventType) {
            return function (e) {
                document.getElementById(eventType).style.background = 'LightGreen';
                
                if (e.shapes && e.shapes.length > 0) {
                    e.shapes.forEach(function (shape) {
                        var properties = shape.getProperties();
                        if (properties && properties.parent_id) {
                            console.log('Shape with parent_id:', properties.parent_id);
                        }
                    });
                }
                setTimeout(function () { document.getElementById(eventType).style.background = 'white'; }, 1000);
            };
        }

